# save two separate 1D arrays to file python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, save

Consider the following example:

There are two one one dimensional arrays x,y:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([4,5,6])
```

I am looking for a method to save both arrays into a single file (txt or csv), where each array is represented as a column, e.g.

```
x   y
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

The only option I found so far is np.savetxt(). I tried to use np.savetxt('test.csv', [test, test2]) but the result

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

is wrong. Also 1 2 3 and 4 5 6 stands in a single cell in the csv.file. Instead I want that each number stands in its own cell (as in the desired example above).

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your data before saving:

```py
np.savetxt('test.csv', np.array([x, y]).T)
```